# python tkinter SyntaxError

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Why I can't make nonlocal variable in Class.

here is code --->

```
    from tkinter import *
     class Note:
         root = Tk()
         nonlocal font_size = 16
         def bigger(event):
             font_size+=5
         root.bind("<Shift-Up>", bigger)
         root.mainloop()
```

output --->

```
           nonlocal font_size = 16
                       ^
           SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `nonlocal variable = value` is not valid syntax. `nonlocal`, just like `global`, is used to "mark" names as nonlocal and global, respectively. It's *not* a special form of variable definition. You can "mark" a name as nonlocal like this:

```
nonlocal variable
```

And then use `variable` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know the answer you must to use **init**(self)